# Как передать в функцию указатель на элемент, следующий за концом этого массива

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Есть функция, принимающая три аргумента: указатель на первый элемент диапазона в массиве, указатель, следующий за концом это диапазона и значение int. Функция должна присвоить каждому элементу диапазона массива это значение int.

```
void set_array(int *begin, int *end, int val) {
   for (int *pt = begin; pt != end; pt++) *pt = value;
}
```

**Вопрос:**  как передать в эту функцию указатель элемент, следующий за концом этого диапазона?

Comment: вызвать функцию, отдав ей вторым параметром указатель на элемент, следующий за последним элементов в диапазоне. Или Вы не понимаете как получить указатель на элемент за последним ? Если `ptr` - указатель на последний элемент в диапазоне, то `++ptr` - указатель на следующий за ним. Главное не разыменовывать его, а только сравнивать с ним.

Comment: @vt-egorov Ну а как сделать так, чтобы ptr указывал на последний элемент массива? Например, чтобы ptr указывал на первый элемент массива надо присвоить ptr имя массива (т. е. адрес первого элемента) ptr = arr; (ptr = &arr[0]).

Comment: а вы как думаете? если ++ptr это следующий элемент массива, сколько надо добавить, чтобы получился последний элемент массива

Comment: В общем наверно надо сделать как-то так: int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int * end = arr + size;
Потом передать в функцию set_array(arr, end, val);

Comment: Наверно так....

Comment: @JustLearn для массивов на стэке это будет работать. На куче - нет. я про `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);`. В stl добавили `std::begin(), std::end()`, они работают и для массивов на стеке тоже, то есть `set_array(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), val);` должно работать

Comment: Как минимум надо четко указать, как и где объявляется массив...

Comment: @vt-egorov,  если массив в куче, то хранить можете только указатель на первый элемент, а для указателей нет  std::begin(), std::end()

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Почему? [Массив на стеке](http://cpp.sh/5xbfo) - все работает. Но только массивы на стеке. На куче не будет. Я так и написал. `" для массивов на стэке это будет работать. На куче - нет."`. И даже написал почему - как-раз из-за вот этой конструкции - `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`. Это так же относится и к `std::begin`, `std::end` - массивы на стеке работают, на куче - нет. Ну в смысле для некоторых особенных указателей есть std::begin/std::end. Видимо, они не указатели а как-то по другому называются. Массивы на стеке, может быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вектора можно вызвать вот так:

```cpp
int m = 6;
vector <int> v(m);
fill(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
```

Для массива вот так:

```cpp
int n = 4;
int a[n] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
fill(a, a + n, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос полностью описывает поведение алгоритма

```
std::fill
```

Вот ссылка на его описание - https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill

Порядок его вызова выглядит следующим образом (сначала посмотрим весь код):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


#define UNUSED(x) (void)(x)


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    constexpr int size{10};
    int data[size] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::vector<int> v1(data, data + size);

    int new_value{1};
    std::fill(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), new_value);

    for (const auto& v: v1) {
        std::cout << v << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вызов std::fill :

```
std::fill(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), new_value);
```

Тут 
std::begin(...) - вернет итератор на 1 элемент.
std::end(...) - вернет то, что Вы и хотели - элемент следующий за последним.

вот линк с описанием std::end - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end

Comment: Спасибо за ответ